# Trying to upload an update package to SC 9.3 and getting "The requested document was not found"

Tags: sitecore-client, packages

When I try to upload a package to install items I am getting a window that reports "The requested document was not found". This started as a vanilla installation of 9.3 onto which I have installed an update with custom code, then I disabled a few lines in the pipelines.config file which still have issues to be resolved. I did not notice the upload issue immediately; I don't know if it was a direct result of this update or some subsequent action I may have taken.

Here's the message I get when I click the "Upload package" button:
[image]

UPDATE:
In the pipeline, I disabled the following:

```
<!--processor type="Website.Core.Robots.RobotsProcessor, Website.Core" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/-->
<!--processor type="Website.Core.Sitemap.SitemapProcessor, Website.Core" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/-->
<!--processor type="Website.Core.ErrorHandling.ExecuteRequestProcessor, Website.Core" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']"/-->
```

Comment: Can you outline what changes you made to the pipeline and code?

Comment: @MichaelWest The code is pretty much just components. The pipeline updates I made, I have added to the original post.

Comment: Why not add just the Sitecore items in the package and the physical files you can deploy seperately. By doing this way, you can sort out the problem is what I think..

Comment: Because you can see the error message when you preview the particular page/ maybe when you load the instance depending on the issue..

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean I am not previewing any pages, I am trying to upload a package.

Comment: Something to consider is to install a new vanilla installation and confirm that package works. Then do a comparison of the show config for each instance to determine precisely what is different.